# Get maximum value from linked list using recursion, Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the maximum value using recursion and a `linked list`

```
  public static int maxOfMyList(MyListOfInts M){
    int max = M.restOfTheInts.firstInt;
    if(M == null) {
        return max;
    }
    if(M.firstInt > max ) {
        max = M.firstInt;
    }
    return  maxOfMyList(M.restOfTheInts);
}
```

However I am getting `Java.lang.NullPointerException` on the declaration of the `int`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (M == null)` then what is `M.restOfTheInts.firstInt`?

Comment: It would be like  list.next.info  (info is the int)

Comment: No, it would be like `null.restOfTheInts.firstInt`

Comment: No, I don't think you have the concept of recursion down.  When you call method `MyListOfInts` with `M`, the method knows only about the `M` you give it.  It doesn't know anything about the `M` lists that were arguments to earlier calls.  So if `M == null`, the method does not have access to _any_ other list elements.  Yes, the method was called from another `MyListOfInts` with a 1-element list, and that one was called from another `MyListOfInts` with a 2-element list, and so on.  But that doesn't matter......

Comment: You have to try to think of each call as a separate "instance" of the method, sort of.  Each "instance" has its own value of `M`, and it doesn't know anything about the other instances.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for the concept. However I do no have a clear idea, on what to compare and what to return.

Comment: If `M` has one element, then you should return that.  If `M` has more than one element, then think about it.  If you know that the first element is X, and the largest value of the rest of the elements is Y, then how can you figure out what is the largest element in the whole list?  If you can figure that out, then you will succeed if you just express this in the code.  The "largest value of the rest of the elements" will be your recursive call.  (I wouldn't worry about the case where `M` is `null`.)

Comment: Got it! Thanks my friend, you really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to pass the linked list node to the recursion tree. Compare the value returned by the child recursive call with current node value and percolate the bigger of the two upwards in the recursion tree. This way you will end up getting the maximum value in the List.

```
int FindMax (ListNode node)
{
     if (node == null) {
        return -1; /* Can be a big negative number */
    }

    int x = FindMax (node.next());
    int max = (x > node.getKey()) ? (x): (node.getKey());
    return max;
}
```

Call the above function passing the `head` of the LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function with first element,

```
public static int maxOfMyList(MyListOfInts M){
    if(M==null){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     }
    //last element
    if( M.next()==null){
        return M.value();//return current value; 
     } 
    return Math.max( M.value(),maxOfMyList(M.next()))
}
```

Assumptions : next() will point to the next element, value() will return the value of the current element.

Without Math.

```
 public static int maxOfMyList(MyListOfInts M,int currentMax){
    if(M==null){
        return currentMax;
     }

     currentMax = M.value()>currentMax?M.value():currentMax;
    //last element
    if( M.next()==null){
        return  currentMax;
     } 

    return  maxOfMyList(M.next()),currentMax)
}
```

Call the function,

```
maxOfMyList(M,M.value());
```

Comment: Nice job.  You haven't helped the OP one bit, since he doesn't really have the concept down.  But you've shown us that you know the answer.  Yay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however, I am not allowed to use Math. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: The second solution is better because it uses **tail recursion**. BTW, as @ajb said, this answer is **correct** but can be **better** to point out what OP's concept about recursion is wrong first...

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, thanks to AJB help.

```
 public static int maxOfMyList(MyListOfInts M){


    if(M.firstInt > M.restOfTheInts.firstInt ) {
         return M.firstInt;
    }else{
        return maxOfMyList(M.restOfTheInts);
    }


}
```

Thanks for the help!